# Can I read Kill Order before Maze Runner?

Tags: suggested-order, the-maze-runner, prequels

I have been very eager to read *The Maze Runner*.
But I have received the book *Kill Order* as a gift.

Generally I am against reading prequels before reading the actual series, but in this case I don't have a choice.

Can somebody tell me if reading *Kill Order* will spoil *The Maze Runner* for me?

No plot spoilers for *The Maze Runner*, please.

Comment: _I don't have a choice_... Maybe just don't read it?

Comment: Possibly get The Maze Runner from the library? I DO recommend keeping the order while reading for this series especially.

Comment: Daft, I don't have the choice of buying Maze Runner, I meant. And no, the library doesn't have it, Bookeater. But thanks. I'll wait a little longer, then. It's just so tempting to read Kill Order -it's right under my nose.

Comment: @Brindha You can always buy a digital version of Maze Runner from Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Maze-Runner-Book-ebook/dp/B002QE3CTY/ref=sr_1_1_twi_kin_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1442330597&sr=8-1&keywords=Maze+Runner+ebook

Comment: How can I make more money? I KNOW!!! Ill make a prequel and specifically state that people that suffer from "No Spoilerus" will have to read the first three books before they read the prequel. This way I dont only get moneyzzz for 1 book but 4! I'm a GENIUS!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the author, his suggestion in [this interview with BookZone](http://bookzone.boyslife.org/lets-talk-author-james-dashner/) is that you should read the original trilogy of books first:

> **Q.** *Could a newcomer to jump into The Kill Order without reading the other Maze Runner books?*
>
> **Dashner:** *I highly recommend that people read the trilogy first because so much of the magic in that story is discovering things piece
>   by piece.*

---

There are a considerable number of reviews [here](http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/993968-what-order-should-i-read-them) with the general concensus of opinion (approx 50:1) among fans of the books that you should read **all three books in the series first, then the prequel novel last.**

Answer (score 2):

> No plot spoilers for The Maze Runner, please.

The Kill Order doesn't really give away any of the plotline of the Maze Runner, but it does reveal a lot of the background behind it. That could be a spoiler as it would take away a lot of the mystery that forms such an important part of the experience of reading The Maze Runner.

Unfortuantely, the Maze Runner also gives away spoilers about The Kill Order, so you can't win...